# perl truncating varchar fields over 255 on syabse database

Tags: database, perl, sybase, sap-ase, dbi

I am running stored procedure and the data in the `varchar(1024)` field is being truncated.  The data inserts without any issues.  When I run my stored procedure to retrieve the data it is getting truncated.
I am using `perl 5, version 22`. Sybase `ASE 15.7` DBI version `1.634`

If I call the stored procedure using sqsh all of the data comes back.  If I call the stored procedure using `pyodbc` all of the data comes back.  When I use perl the `varchar 1024` field is being truncated to 255 characters.
I have tired setting `$dbh->{'LongReadLen'} = 4000;` but nothing.

Comment: Does the situation (And fix) described [here](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=663835) apply to your case?

Comment: Gave that a shot and isn't working.  I tried `$dbh-do("set textsize <100000");`  That threw an error.  Tried `$dbh->do("set textsize 100000");` Nothing changed.  Still truncating the varchar to 255.

Comment: Does `DBI` limit the varchar field to 255?

Comment: It might help to set the environment variable `DBI_TRACE` to some value 1-15 (though 15 gives A LOT) of info, to see more of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the store procedure and casted the varchar as text and that worked.  I did come across I can't find the link.  But the version of free tds I am using is older and freetds does limit varchar to 255.  I would have to upgrade to a different version.